# Function to extract tweets from user's timeline is looping an

Tags: python, tweepy

When I run the function, the function brings back around 200 tweets and then loops, until it gets to the total number of tweets the user actually has. So it will repeat the 200 tweets until it reaches that number.

```
def extract_tweets(userid):
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = userid, 
                                count = 200, 
                                include_rts = True, 
                                tweet_mode = 'extended')
    for info in tweets[:3]:
        print('ID: {}'.format(info.id))
        print(info.created_at)
        print(info.full_text)
        print('\n')
    all_tweets = []
    all_tweets.extend(tweets)
    oldest_id = tweets[-1].id
    tweet_num = api.get_user(userid).statuses_count
    while len(all_tweets) < tweet_num: 
        tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = userid, 
                                count = 200, 
                                tweet_mode = 'extended')
        if len(tweets) == 1000: 
            break 
        oldest_id = tweets[-1].id
        all_tweets.extend(tweets)
    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str,
                  tweet.created_at,
                  tweet.favorite_count,
                  tweet.retweet_count,
                  tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')]
                for idx, tweet in enumerate(all_tweets)]
    df = DataFrame(outtweets, columns =['id', 'created_at', 'favorite_count', 'retweet_count', 'text'])
    df.to_csv('%s_tweets.csv' % userid, index = False)
    df.head(3)
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Your break condition (len(tweets) == 1000) will never be true as the maximum number of tweets return is 200. If you want to exit the loop when all the user tweets are collected, the break condition should be:

```
if len(tweets) == 0: 
            break
```